# how to reduce travis build time?

Tags: travis-ci

I have configured github repository for travis-ci, ref [.travis.yml](https://github.com/ProjectKaiser/pk-realm/blob/master/.travis.yml)

It takes almost two minutes to build, travis is busy with the actions like this:
[image: Build screen]

Is there a way to speed-up the process? I have read [Migrating from legacy to container-based infrastructure](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/migrating-from-legacy/) but seems that simply "sudo: false" does not work. Can I do something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get rid of updating libc by moving to the trusty environment. The following will probably have least overhead:

```
sudo: false
dist: trusty
```